# How to select specific cells with Confidence Interval Convergence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I have an excel sheet that is the finished product of an R analysis. It has multiple columns and each cell has a value(2.5%,97.5%). I want to know how to get the count for each column of cells that successfully had the value within the confidence interval. I could create a sample sheet, but I am not sure how to post one. It should pretty straightforward what it looks like. I just need the totals as a percentage at the bottom of each column.

Let me know if you need any more information. I am very new to Excel, so I don't have a clear direction yet.

Comment: does each cell have a pair of values like you mentioned (2.5%, 97.5%), or rather, a single value? Regardless, how should counting work (ie, greater than x less than y, etc).

Comment: @Isolated. Yes each cell is set up like this; 3(2,4), where (3,4) is the confidence interval. I want to count the number of cells that have the value within the confidence interval. In this case it is true, because 2<3<4. Does this make sense?

Comment: In the example from your comment, is (2,4) or (3,4) in parenthesis? I'm not quite understanding this. Would you be able to post a few examples where the condition is met and also not met.